# Anylogic, split an agent in multiple different agent types

Tags: anylogic, event-simulation

I've a problem with a simulation in anylogic. 
I have an item (agent) that must be processed by a resource, the result of this service block is the starting object and two different documents which are processed in two separate offices and which at the end of the flow will have to be linked to the article in question. 
I can't find a way to do this division into 3 different agents, or in general, to model this flow.
Thanks in advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 2 split blocks to generate 2 independent documents and connect them through a variable or link to agents... maybe each original agent has an id and the copies in the split block will have something like `agent.id=original.id;`
Then after, when the documents are processed you can check for which ones have the same id to merge them into an article...

but if you want to get more complicated, there's also the following option:

create 2 enter blocks (enter1 and enter2), one for each document. I will assume your documents correspond to 2 different agent types called Document1 and Document2

On each one of the agent types, you will add a link to agents in order to be able to connect the documents to each other. Read more on link to agents on the help documentation if you don't know what that is.

At the end of the service block, on the on exit action, you can do the following:

```
Document1 doc1=add_Document1();
Document2 doc2=add_Document2();
doc1.linkToDoc2.connectTo(doc2);
enter1.take(doc1);
enter2.take(doc2);
```

I don't know if your original agent has to be connected, but you would follow the same principle to do that.

Later, you can just check if the connected docs are completed in order to join them in an article again.

Comment: Thanks a lot Felipe!